# What is the function that the stops php from serving the page until finished processing

Tags: php

There is a function in php that stops it from progressively serving the page, and instead makes it wait until everything is processed. This function is usually used so you can redirect even after the headers are sent - I forgot the name and my google queries didn't return anything - can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you looking for [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php)?

Answer (score 1):

the exact function you're looking for is

```
ob_start()
```